# Adjust size of background image automatically in Powerpoint using VBA (running from Excel)

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

While manually setting an image as background in Powerpoint, the resizing is taken care of automatically and appears properly.

[image]

But when I do it through VBA the image gets distorted;

[image]

Here's the VBA code I have;

```
With oSlide.Background.Fill
     .UserPicture "C:\Images\sample.jpg"
End With
```

How do I get the image fit right?

Comment: is your VBA code run from Excel ? or from PowerPoint itself ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I'm running it from Excel

Comment: Hey @Richie , Would resizing the image so that it has the same Height/Width proportion as the slide background does work?

Comment: @TheSilkCode Is it the same thing (height/width proportion) that happens when we set the background image manually?

Comment: So basically what's happening is the Height/Width ratio of the slide is different than the image- so when you try and apply the image to the background one aspect, either the Height or Width, gets stretched out further which is what gives it the distorted look... but if the image is already the correct H/W ratio, then when it gets stretched out to cover the background it will already be in the correct H/W ratio and wont get distorted...